# Are there readable reference implementations for the cryptographic primitives used by Ethereum?

Tags: clients

For example, [this](https://github.com/gvanas/KeccakCodePackage/blob/master/Standalone/CompactFIPS202/Python/CompactFIPS202.py) Python file implements SHA3 in a compact and very readable form in Python. I wonder if we have those compact implementations for the primitives used on Ethereum, in special Keccak (not SHA3) and ECDSA (signing and recover).

Answer (score 1):

For Keccak the `delimitedSuffix` should be `0x01` instead of `0x06` in SHA3.

So it should look like

```
def Keccak_256(inputBytes):
    return Keccak(1088, 512, inputBytes, 0x01, 256//8)
```